# Mozilla firefox add-on to redirect url from one domain name to another domain without changing the complete url

Tags: firefox

I want to know is there any add-on to redirect url in mozilla firefox. In Google Chrome there is an add-on `Switcheroo`. I need the url switcher like this in mozilla firefox. I have already tried with redirect url add-on of mozilla. But its not redirecting correctly.

**Requirements:**

I need to test the localhost portal pages. But in few places the dev environment url is hard coded. I want to redirect those urls to localhost to test the changes which I made in local.

Eg redirection:

`protocol://dev_hostname:dev_portnubmer/wps/portal/abcd/xyz/u!/abcd`

should be redirected to

`protocol://localhost:localhostPortnumber/wps/portal/abcd/xyz/u!/abcd`

For this redirection in google chrome switcheroo add-on I have configured like this:-http://dev_hostname:dev_portnubmer ---> http://localhost:localhostPortnumber. The add-on changing the protocol, domain name, port number. It's not changing the rest of the url part. Its working well as I expected. But in Mozilla I need an add-on like this.

Comment: Recommend Reading - https://medium.com/@requestly_ext/chrome-extensions-for-redirecting-urls-redirector-requestly-switcheroo-d9870ba77c22 to know/compare the features provided by these extensions. **Disclaimer: I built Requestly.**

Comment: This question isn't suitable for StackOverflow. https://superuser.com/ could be a better place.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: In that case you should use the Flag button to report it. I have done so.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Requestly](http://www.requestly.in/) extension which is available for both Chrome and Firefox. It has a feature to replace parts of URL which matches a given text or pattern instead of redirecting to a different URL altogether, basically what Switcheroo does. It has other features as well.

For your particular use case, you can follow these steps -

1. Install [Requestly](http://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/04/07/install-requestly-in-chrome-and-firefox/)
2. Click on `r` icon in address bar
3. Click on (+) Green Icon to create a new Rule
4. Select `Replace Rule`
5. Replace `dev_hostname:dev_portnubmer` with `localhost:localhostPortnumber`
6. Save

Test your app now.

Comment: Does this affect all URL resolution, or only for pages you navigate to? Like, does it affect <img src=> urls?

Comment: this works flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

There is a add-on available for mozilla to redirect url which is **Redirector**.

I have read the help provided by the Redirector add-on, there they have explained the usage of it clearly.

Comment: This doesn't appear to replace URIs, it actually just redirects the entire browser page, which isn't what Switcharoo does, unfortunately.